# Is there any way to specifically target the specified port number of the specified domain name for TCP interception?

Tags: c, ssl, web, https, tcp

Mine has set up a web server on Tencent Cloud server. However, since I have not filed the website with the government, accessing port 443 of the server through the domain name will be blocked, and the Chromium browser will display TCP RSET.

But I don’t use the domain name, I changed to the IP address to access, except that the SSL certificate verification failed (because my certificate is a domain name certificate), I can ask the server normally.

I know that all domain name connections need to query DNS first to obtain an IP address, and then use the IP to access the server. My domain name resolution is normal, and the correct IP can be obtained.

I tried to use openssl to simulate Chromium requests, the main code is as follows:

Query DNS:

```c
hostent *hostent = gethostbyname("www.example.com");
in_addr ip;
memcpy(&(ip.s_addr), hostent->h_addr_list[0], hostent->h_length);
```

Create socket:

```c
const int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sockaddr_in sock_address;
sock_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
sock_address.sin_port = htons(443);
sock_address.sin_addr = ip;
int error = connect(sock, (sockaddr *) &sock_address, sizeof(sockaddr));
if (error) {
    fprintf(log_err, "The socket connection failed.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

SSL handshake:

```c
SSL_library_init();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
SSL_load_error_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

const SSL_METHOD *sslMethod = SSLv23_client_method();
SSL_CTX *sslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(sslMethod);
if (!sslCtx) {
    fprintf(log_err, "SSL_CTX_new failed\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(log_err);
    return 1;
}

SSL *ssl = SSL_new(sslCtx);
if (!ssl) {
    fprintf(log_err, "ssl handle creation failed.\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(log_err);
    return 1;
}
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
SSL_connect(ssl);
```

send http header:

```c
char *head_line = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, head_line, (int) strlen(head_line));
head_line = "Host: www.example.com:443\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, head_line, (int) strlen(head_line));
head_line = "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, head_line, (int) strlen(head_line));
head_line = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, head_line, (int) strlen(head_line));
head_line = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, head_line, (int) strlen(head_line));
head_line = "\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, head_line, (int) strlen(head_line));
```

The above code can access my WEB server normally.

This is some environmental information.

```
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
system: Linux 5.10.59-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 15 13:11:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Chromium version: 92.0.4515.159 (release) Arch Linux （64 位）
```

Assuming that the IP corresponding to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is 127.0.0.1,
Enter https://127.0.0.1/ in the browser to access normally, but use https://www.example.com/ to access, because of the national government's blockade, TCP RSET will appear. I want to know what is the technical principle of this interception. Under normal circumstances, whether it is using IP or domain name, it should be inaccessible, right?

And I think the code above should be the same as Chromium's request steps, but why is there a different result? The request sent by my program was not intercepted, but the request from Chromium was intercepted?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I have not fully understood what your question is. What does it mean "there is any way to intercept only port 443 through the domain name without affecting the IP access to port 443"?

Comment: Assuming that the IP corresponding to www.example.com is 127.0.0.1,
In the browser, entering https://127.0.0.1/ can be accessed normally, but using https://www.example.com/ due to government interception, TCP RSET will appear. I want to know what is the technical principle of this interception. Under normal circumstances, whether it is using IP or domain name, shouldn't it be inaccessible?

Comment: This sounds like DNS interception. If a third party (like the ISP or the government or whoever) intercepts DNS queries, the usual way to bypass this is to use an alternative not-intercepted DNS server. For instance, by default home routers are configured to use the ISP DNS server, but if you change the DNS server (either in the router or in all the computers connected to it) to another DNS (like `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1`) the DNS interception will usually not happen anymore. In case of more advanced DNS interceptions, consider using DNSSEC protocol (i.e.: an encrypted version of DNS).

Comment: I may write an answer with additional details about how interceptions may happen, and how to bypass them (as long as the IP address is not blocked), if you want.

Comment: No, it is not a DNS interception. I have confirmed that the IP obtained by the DNS query is correct.

Comment: Another reason may be linked to the HTTP protocol and how web servers (like Apache and nginx) respond to HTTP requests: in the HTTP protocol, making a request to `http://1.2.3.4` and to `http://example.com` are not the exact same thing (even if `example.com` resolves to `1.2.3.4`); that's because in the HTTP request you're telling the web server the name of the server that you want to contact (either `1.2.3.4` or `example.com`) and the web server may refuse connections to `example.com` but not to `1.2.3.4`.

Comment: This is also valid for HTTPS requests, because the TLS protocol (used by HTTPS) contains information about the server name (like `example.com`) in a field called SNI. This is used by web servers mostly to provide different certificates for different server names (even if the IP address is always the same).

Comment: In other words, in my HTTPS request simulation program, is it because of the lack of the TLS protocol SNI field that my program can request success, but the browser request fails?

Comment: Well, yes, it may be. Maybe a firewall between your computer and the web server has been configured to block connections to `example.com` (and the firewall looks in the SNI field for this information). The supposed firewall may be your ISP's, for example. The most effective way to bypass this kind of restriction is to use a VPN, usually. P.S.: you can try adding the SNI field to your TLS request in your program, to confirm this behavior (you may do it with function `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Setting SSL_set_tlsext_host_name for SSL will indeed cause the SSL handshake to fail, and TCP will suddenly disconnect.